# Peer to peer connection between two machines *each* behind a double NAT

Tags: router, vlc-media-player, nat

I am in Australia and I am using KOGAN as mobile data provider. I could use another one, but I don't know yet if that would solve the problem I have.

In short, my setup is:

```
PC1 (AUDIO Transmitter):
IP 192.168.8.100
GW:192.168.8.1
4G modem 1:
LAN IP: 192.168.8.1
WAN IP: 10.230.208.90
WAN GW IP: 10.230.208.89
```

If I check "whatsmyip" for PC1 I get 120.16.82.177 (dynamic, changes in time)

```
PC2 (AUDIO receiver):
IP 192.168.1.50
GW:192.168.1.1
4G modem 2:
LAN IP: 192.168.1.1
WAN IP: 10.239.18.67
WAN GW IP: <not shown by my 4G modem ...>
```

If I check "whatsmyip" for PC2 I get 120.16.32.42 (dynamic, changes in time)

So, both computers are behind a double NAT; so far, all is clear.

I obviously do not have any direct control over KOGAN's (the mobile data provider) routers/firewalls, and an email sent last week has gone unanswered so far, and obviously I do have full control on my own 4G routers, where I could set up port forwarding etcetera, but this would not work as there would be no PF in KOGAN's routers.

I stumbled upon PWNAT, which looks like is capable of establishing a direct link between PC1 and PC2.

But I can't work around my head on how exactly I should use PWNAT in my specific circumstances.

What I am trying to achieve is to run VLC on both machines; one to send an audio UDP stream to the other one receiving  it with VLC as well.

On the transmitting PC I would run:

```
vlc music.mp3 :sout=#udp{dst=120.16.32.42:1234} :no-sout-all :sout-keep
```

on the receiving side, just

```
vlc udp://@:1234
```

As it stands now, when my UDP packets arrive at 120.16.32.42:1234 they are dropped (I suppose) and end of story.

So, how can achieve this?

Note: the idea is to achieve the lowest possible delay/latency; that's why I am using two 4G modems with the same provider. So that I would use the shortest local route available.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried using the 10.0.0.0/8 IP addresses and they are not routable inside your ISP's network?

I have never used PWNAT, but it looks like a really ingenious tool. It looks like the command you might run is...

```
Server side allowing anyone to proxy:
  ./pwnat -s
  vlc music.mp3 :rtp={sdp=rtsp://:1234/} :no-sout-all :sout-keep

Client wanting to connect:
  ./pwnat -c 21234 120.16.82.177 192.168.8.100 1234
  vlc rtsp://localhost:1234
```

Barring options thus far, I think your next best option is to set up a VPN server somewhere nearby that does have a usable public IP and connect both machines to that. Your latency will suffer.

Comment: Hi Andy, ok, I will try your suggestion and post the results.
No, haven' tried using 10.0.0.0/8, but will investigate.